# How to read files from a file in C++ using fread and buffering?

Tags: c++, file, io, fread

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

FILE *in, *out;

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    in = fopen("share.in", "r");
    int days;
    int size;
    int offset = 0;
    fscanf(in, "%d", &days);

    fseek(in, 0L, SEEK_END);

#if defined(_WIN32)
    size = ftell(in) - 1;
#elif defined (_WIN64)
    size = ftell(in) - 1;
#else
    size = ftell(in);
#endif // defined

    fseek(in, 0L, SEEK_SET);

    char *buffer = (char*) malloc(size + 1);
    char *token;

    fread(buffer, 1, size, in);
    buffer[size] = '\n';

    int *values = (int*) malloc(days * sizeof(int));
    int i;

    while (*buffer != '\n'){
        buffer++;
    }

    buffer++;
    cout << days << endl;
    cout << endl;

    for (i = 0; i < days; i++){
        values[i] = 0;

        while (*buffer != '\n'){
            values[i] = (values[i] * 10) + (*buffer - '0');
            buffer++;
        }

        buffer++;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < days; i++){
        cout << values[i] << endl;
    }

}
```

The file I want to read is this:

```
20 
10 
7
19
20
19
7
1
1
514
8
5665
10
20
17
16
20
17
20
2
16
```

I want the first to be stored in the variable days which is tha size of the array, and the rest in the array, but it reads everything but the last number. ***Each number is in an new line.*** What can I change about it? I am thinking sth in the last while condition. Thank you

Comment: Besides the `using namespace std;` uglyness an some cout, the question is not C++, please tag it C

Comment: In C++, I suggest using `std::istream::read` into a `std::vector<char>` or an `std::string`.  You can use `std::istringstream` to read from the vector as if the vector were an input stream.  No need for you to use dynamic memory.

Comment: Search StackOverflow for "c++ read from file integer" or "c++ read from file array".

Comment: If this were a C language program, I would suggest you use `sscanf` to convert the text you read in, into internal integers.  The `sscanf` reads from a character buffer similar to how `fscanf` reads from a file.

Answer (score 4):

If you're going to write C++, write it as C++. I'd do the job something like this:

```
std::ifstream in("share.in");

int days;
in >> days;

std::vector<int> data { std::istream_iterator<int>(in),
                        std::istream_iterator<int>() };

assert(days == data.size());
```

For real code, the `assert` is optional--primarily there to show that we expect the first number we read to match the number of other items we read from the file.